# subsetting data frame without using column names

Tags: r, subset

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this or if I might be running into some unforeseen trouble. I need to subset from a data frame but I do not want to use the column names. I'd need do it by referencing the *column number*.

```
data <- data.frame(col1= c(50, 20, NA, 100, 50), 
                   col2= c(NA, 25, 125, 50, NA),
                   col3= c(NA, 100, 15, 55, 25),
                   col4= c(NA, 30, 125, 100, NA),
                   col5= c(80, 25, 75, 40, NA))
```

Suppose I want to subset the data frame and keep only the row that contain 3 consecutive NAs before a valid number in column 5. Best I can come up with *without using column names* is this:

```
sub <- data[(which(is.na(data[2]) & 
                   is.na(data[3]) & 
                   is.na(data[4]) & 
                   !is.na(data[5]))), ]
```

Anyone see any trouble with this or know of a better way? I'm worried about using subsets within subsets although every thing appears to be working as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to condense your code a little, you can do something like:

```
> data[rowSums(is.na(data[2:4])) == 3 & !is.na(data[5]), ]
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1   50   NA   NA   NA   80
```

Comment: Why is column 1 being excluded from consideration?

Comment: @BondedDust, because it seems like that's what the OP is after based on their code (though their description is a little ambiguous).

Comment: (+1) I just finished this exact code 12 minutes late.  By the way, `soread()` is a really useful function. :-)

Comment: @BondedDust, I think he's referring to https://github.com/sebastian-c/overflow/blob/master/R/soread.R

Comment: OK, although I thought I could see how spread migh apply here. I already had a function I had whipped up to do that job but I think I'll ask a question regarding a cognate problem with reading SO questions that are zoo or xts screen output. Maybe there could be automatic detection inside an expanded soread?